# Transmitting data between classes

Tags: c++, qt, class

My code is set up in this way: the main window with a QTableWidget, and a control panel created with a different class from the MainWindow. In the control panel control there is a QListWidget where I want to load the titles of the header from the table, but being QTableWidget private, how can I pass data between the two classes?

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "QControlPanel.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTableWidget>


namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    class GenerateXML;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~MainWindow();

public slots:

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTableWidget* m_pTableWidget;
    QControlPanel* preferences;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    this->setWindowIcon(QIcon("DrawItem.ico"));
    this->setWindowTitle("DrawItem");
    resize(890, 475);

    m_pTableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
    m_TableHeader<<"A"<<"B"<<"C"<<"D"<<"E";
    m_pTableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(m_TableHeader);
    m_pTableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
    m_pTableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    m_pTableWidget->move(30, 75);
    m_pTableWidget->resize(410, 151);

    preferences = new QControlPanel(this);
}
```

QControlPanel.h

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QTableWidget>

#ifndef QCONTROLPANEL_H
#define QCONTROLPANEL_H

class QControlPanel : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QControlPanel(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~QControlPanel();

public slots:
    void customHeader(QTableWidget *table);

private:
    QListWidget *headerlist;

private slots:

};

#endif
```

QControlPanel.cpp

```
#include "QControlPanel.h"

QControlPanel::QControlPanel(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    headerlist = new QListWidget(inputHeader);
    headerlist->setGeometry(140, 15, 140, 130);
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to be able to edit the list of available column in your table widget from a configuration window or something like that?

Comment: I guess there are 2 ways of doing this: you either setup your list to retrieve the current headers of the table, or you setup your table to retrieve the allowed list of header from the list? Anyway, can't you have `MainWindow` pass a pointer of one object to the other at build time, so that they may see each other?

Comment: You may want to accomplish this using a custom model that both the QListWidget and QTableWidget share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a signal in the `QControlPanel` class which retrieves the headers. So `QControlPanel` can be like :

```
class QControlPanel : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QControlPanel(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~QControlPanel();

signals:

    QStringList getHeaders();

private:
    QListWidget *headerlist;
};
```

And connect the `getHeaders()` signal to a slot of the class which contains  the list of columns to retrieve them. This should be done in the constructor of the `MainWindow` :

```
connect(preferences,SIGNAL(getHeaders()),this,SLOT(getTableHeader()));
```

`getTableHeader()` is a slot in `MainWindow` which return the header columns :

```
QStringList getTableHeader()
{
    return m_TableHeader;
}
```

Now you can access the headers in `QControlPanel` :

```
QControlPanel::QControlPanel(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    headerlist = new QListWidget();
    headerlist->insertItems(0, getHeaders());
}
```